# Turning Normalized Int to Non-normalized Int That Doesnt Start At 0

Tags: c#, math

So i have a normalized value on the range starts at 43200 to 64800. I am wondering how i take this normalized value and turn it back from its normalized state to a marginal state. I am not sure at all what the math would be. I know if it started at 0 it would just be the normalized value * maximum value, but not sure what it is for this circumstance.

Comment: Hey, you forgot Malbolge.

Comment: Why don't you pick one language?

Comment: Cause i dont need to know it in the specific language, just need help with the math and logic behind it, changed it

Comment: Just math? Then you 're in the wrong place.

Comment: What im saying is , im not asking for a snippet of code but to understand how to undo it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To normalize: subtract 43200 from all values and divide them with 64800 - 43200 = 21600.

To change back: multiply each normalized value with 21600 and add 43200 to them.